# How to call a function from a lua file of a c++/lua project on interactive terminal?

Tags: lua

I'm reading some source codes of  a project, which is a combination of c++ and lua, they are interwined through luabind.

There is a la.lua file, in which there is a function exec(arg). The lua file also uses functions/variables from other lua file, so it has statements as below in the beginning

```
module(..., package.seeall);
print("Loading "..debug.getinfo(1).source.."...") 
require "client_config"
```

now I want to run la.exec() from interactive terminal(on linux), but I get errors like

```
attempt to index global 'lg' (a nil value)
```

if I want to import la.lua, I get

```
require "la"
Loading @./la.lua...
./la.lua:68: attempt to index global 'ld' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
./lg.lua:68: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
stdin:1: in main chunk
[C]: ?
```

what can I do?

Comment: Fix this one. `./la.lua:68: attempt to index global 'ld' (a nil value)`

Comment: @moteus the issue is how to fix it?

Comment: hard to say without `la.lua`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what could be going wrong?

(Really general guesswork following, there's not much information in what you provided…)

One option is that you're **missing dependencies** because the files don't properly `require` all the things they depend on.  (If A depends on & `require`s B and then C, and C depends on B but doesn't `require` it because it's implicitly loaded by A, directly loading C will fail.)  So if you throw some hours at tracking down & fixing dependencies, things might suddenly work.

(However, depending on how the modules are written this may be impossible without *a lot* of restructuring.  As an example, unless you set `package.loaded[`*`"foo"`*`]` to *`foo`*'s module table in *`foo`* *before* loading submdules, those submodules cannot `require`*`"foo"`*.  (Luckily, `module` does that, in newer code without `module` that's often forgotten – and then you'll get an endless loop (until the stack overflows) of *`foo`* loading other modules which load *`foo`* which loads other modules which …)  Further, while "fixing" things so they load in the interpreter you might accidentally break the load order used by the program/library under normal operation which you won't notice until you try to run that one normally again.  So it may simply cost too much time to fix dependencies.  You *might* still be able to track down enough to construct a long `lua -l`*`foo`*`-l`*`bar`*`…` one-off dependency list which might get things to run, but don't depend on it.)

Another option is that there are **missing parts provided by C(++) modules**.  If these are written in the style of a Lua library (i.e. they have `luaopen_FOO`), they might load in the interpreter.  (IIRC that's unlikely for C++ because it expects the main program to be C++-aware but `lua` is (usually? always?) plain C.)  It's also possible that these modules don't work that way and need to be loaded in some other way.  Yet another possibility might be that the **main program pre-defines things** in the Lua state(s) that it creates, which means that there is no module that you could load to get those things.

---

While there are some more variations on the above, these should be all of the general categories.  If you suspect that your problem is the first one (merely missing dependency information), maybe throw some more time at this as you have a pretty good chance of getting it to work.  If you suspect it's one of the latter two, there's a very high chance that you won't get it to work (at least not directly).

You might be able to side-step that problem by patching the program to open up a REPL and then do whatever it is you want to do from there.  (The simplest way to do that is to call `debug.debug()`.  It's really limited (no multiline, no implicit `return`, crappy error information), but if you need/want something better, something that behaves very much like the normal Lua REPL can be written in ~30 lines or so of Lua.)